# R. Separate a string into 2 columns at first number

Tags: r

I have a column with a lot of data of the form "Male25" indicating sex and age. I just want to separate the column into two, one with the sex and the other one with the age. What is the best way to do that in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `separate`

```
library(tidyverse)
as_tibble("Male25" ) %>%
       separate(value, into = c("sex", "age"), "(?<=[a-z])(?=[0-9])", convert = TRUE)
# A tibble: 1 x 2
#  sex     age
#* <chr> <int>
#1 Male     25
```

Comment: `strcapture("(\\w+)(\\d+)","male25",data.frame(name=character(),age=numeric()))`

Answer (score 0):

## you can try both the methods

```
d <- data.frame(a=c("male25","female24","male36","female20"))

cbind(a1=gsub("\\d","",d$a),a2=gsub("\\D","",d$a))

c <- data.frame(a1=gsub("\\d","",d$a),a2=as.numeric(gsub("\\D","",d$a)))
```